# How to access content of a broadcast variable

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I need do some calculation within a function that uses a broadcast value

```
json_data = text.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
 ....
# code to calculate average and generate tuple with json_data['jsontag'] and avgvalue
some rdd filtsubavg with tuples of (jsontag, avgvalue)
V = sc.broadcast(filtsubavg.collect())
com = json_data.map(lambda l:l['jsontag'],l) 
res = com.map(lambda (cmtag,cm): get_val(cmtag,cm,V))
```

How can I access V in my function if I need to say divide by the avgvalue.

```
def get_val(jsontag,cm,v):
    r1 = cm[jsontag]
    r2 = cm[value]/(get corresponding value for jsontag in v)
    return (r1,r2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access content of the broadcast variable you can use its `value` property:

```
V.value
```

If you want to use it as a lookup table it would makes sense to collect it as map (dictionary):

```
V = sc.broadcast(filtsubavg.collectAsMap())
```

Then you can simply use:

```
cm[value] / V.value.get(v)
```

Comment: when i changed from collect() to collectAsMap() and used the .get feature, it did work! Thanks